# State space system identification

Tags: state-space, system-identification

Suppose I have a real (physical) dynamical system with some sensors and actuators, and I also have an idealized state-space model of this same system.  How, in general, can I adjust the model to match the real system?

My experience is with frequency-domain analysis.  My first reaction would be to measure swept-sine transfer functions, and to calculate parameters of my system from the location of resonances or poles in the measured data.

Is there a better, more general technique for system identification in the state-space representation?

Comment: Is the system assumed to be linear? If it is, then a frequency response should be sufficient to characterize it.

Comment: Yes, but how do you put the experimental frequency domain data into the state space form?

Answer (score 1):

The experimental frequency domain data gives you information on the input-output behavior of the system. If the system is assumed to be linear and time-invariant (LTI), this information will be in the form of a transfer function. Given a transfer function, there are infinitely many state-space realizations that yield the same input-output behavior and, thus, are I/O-equivalent.

Having said that, you may want to take a look at the [Adaptive Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_control) literature.